# Clear state used in ProcessWindowFunction of a Flink job

Tags: apache-flink

I'm using ProcessWindowFunction in my job and keeping a StateValue.
My goal is to keep the value in the state for more than 1 window, meaning the state won't be cleared at the end of each window.
I have 2 problems:

1. How can I clear the state? is there any option to set a trigger and use it for clearing the state?
   (When using state in ProcessFunction I'm able to set a trigger in order to do this purge even when there are no new events)
2. Is there a way to build a unit test to check the behavior of the my ProcessWindowFunction implementation (and the state specifically)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. ProcessWindowFunction has a clear method that is called when any per-window state you've created should be cleared. You are expected to implement this method if you are using windowState ([docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/functions/windowing/ProcessWindowFunction.html#clear-org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.windowing.ProcessWindowFunction.Context-)). I'm not sure if there's a way to clear the globalState for stale keys.
2. Flink itself has lots of tests, and it can be reasonable to reuse the OneInputStreamOperatorTestHarness and TwoIntputStreamOperatorTestHarness in your own applications, but these are NOT part of the public API, and might change at any time. Moreover, the internal windowing tests don't appear to use these harnesses -- and I'm not seeing anything in the Flink sources that I would want to leverage if I were writing tests for this.

Comment: Thanks David!
1) I'm not sure this is exactly what I've meant for, so I'll try to rephrase my question - 
Flink's ProcessWindowFunction documentation states that 'globalState() ... is not scoped to a window'.
I think this is the state that I'm interested in using.
My question is how can I trigger a clear call if I'd like to keep the value it's holding for multiple windows? I'm not interested in clearing the state in each trigger of a window.

2) You've mentioned test harnesses - is it a legit way of testing Flink operators? Is it going to be added to Flink's official API?

Comment: I've expanded my answer.